# property is trying to access the value from System.Windows.FrameworkElement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Anyone please try this scenario and share idea to resolve the issue which am facing.

Scenario:

In my class(inherited from Control)  just am have declared the property FlowDirection which is the type of BulletGraphFlowDirection(Enum (Forward, Backward)).

I have used the new Keyword to FlowDirection to resolve warning which I get.

Warning 'DirectionSfBulletGraph1.MyClass.FlowDirection' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FlowDirection'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

```
    public enum BulletGraphFlowDirection
    {
        Forward,
        Backward
    }
public class MyClass : Control
{

    public new BulletGraphFlowDirection FlowDirection
    {
        get { return (BulletGraphFlowDirection)GetValue(FlowDirectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FlowDirectionProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FlowDirection.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public new static readonly DependencyProperty FlowDirectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FlowDirection", typeof(BulletGraphFlowDirection), typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(BulletGraphFlowDirection.Backward));
}
```

Issue:

When I try to set the property FlowDirection value in Xaml page it’s just thrown the error message” Backward is not a valid value for FlowDirection ”.

```
<local:MyClass x:Name="myClass" FlowDirection="Backward"/>
```

My guess is the FlowDirection property is trying to access the value from System.Windows.FrameworkElement. FlowDirection'(Enum(LeftToRight,RightToLeft))

Am not getting error when the property value is set through code behind.

```
myClass.FlowDirection = BulletGraphFlowDirection.Backward;
```

Why am I  getting issue when declared from Xaml page Its very difficult to found root cause of it. Please share me idea to resolve.

Regards,

Jeyasri M

Comment: Why not just name the property something else? Like say BulletFlowDirection

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my doubt is when the property is set in code behind FlowDirection property access the value from its derived class not from base(Control),if the problem is using new keyword in DP then the scenario should not be work when set in code behind also.If I used new Keyword then the FlowDirection property not inherited from base(Control) Class, but still it’s trying to access the base class property value only from XAML declaration not from code behind.

Comment: FYI.I have tried the same scenario in WinRT project for that no issues.but don't know the reason issue with WPF platform.

Answer (score -1):

Well, as you said, it tries to use the value of the original FlowDirection.

The reason is that hiding != overriding. So if your element is stored in a collection of type Control and FlowDirection is called on its elements then the Control.FlowDirection will be called and not the MyClass.FlowDirection. Probably your control is handled as Control and not MyClass when it tries to parse the xaml and initialize the view.

When you set the value in code-behind you specify it explicitly that you want to set the MyClass.FlowDirection by using a MyClass typed variable.

If you would instantiate this variable as:

```
Control myClass = new MyClass();
```

Then

```
myClass.FlowDirection = BulletGraphFlowDirection.Backward;
```

wouldn't work either in my opinion.

As Karmacon suggested, changing the name will solve the problem. (I guess that forces the xaml parser to handle your control as MyClass and not Control)